# как сделать поиск регуляркой слов в произвольном порядке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

В тексте есть слова "one", "two" и другие.

Как одной регуляркой найти одновременное наличие всех этих слов в тексте?
Очередность этих слов неизвестна.

Язык java, но это не принципиально, главное - конструкция регулярного выражения.

Спасибо всем, кто откликнется.

Comment: А регулярка — это принципиально?

Comment: Гораздо проще без регулярки поискать первое слово, а затем второе. (Могу поспорить, будет скорее.) Если слов много, есть классический [алгоритм Ахо—Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Comment: Поясните, что означает `найти одновременное наличие`