# Проверить есть ли в тексте слова, регулярным выражением

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение, которое проверить есть ли в тексте слова - `qwe`,`asd`,`zxc`, они могут являться частью слова. Если делать по порядку `qwe.*asd.*zxc.*`, можно через | перечислить все возможные варианты последовательностей, а как сделать эту задачу проще?

По типу:

```
SELECT 'набор симовлов' REGEXP 'регулярное варажение';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> мне нужно, чтобы они все встречались обязательно

```
(?=.*qwe)(?=.*asd)(?=.*zxc)
```

Comment: SELECT 'qweasdzxc' REGEXP '(?=.*qwe)(?=.*asd)(?=.*zxc)';
Выдал ошибку 1139. Я что-то не правильно делаю? Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Мне кажется нужно писать грамоздное выражение.Спасибо за редактирование моего вопроса, так намного понятнее.Я нашел похожую задачу(их регулярное выражение не работает в mysql):http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416913/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: @Egor_K, возможно, mysql не умеет предпросмотр.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня было такое подозрение, так как в мануалах по регулярным выражениям в MYSQL намного меньше команд, чем просто регуляных выражений. Я думал я просто что-то недопонял в справочниках!

Answer (score 0):

примерно так (возвратит `1` при совпадении одной из комбинаций):

```
select 'набор симовлов' regexp 'qwe|asd|zxc';
```

а если требуется, чтобы в строке были все три комбинации, то примерно так:

```
select 'набор симовлов' regexp 'qwe' and 'набор симовлов' regexp 'asd' and 'набор симовлов' regexp 'zxc';
```

Comment: qwe|asd|zxc мне нужно, чтобы они все встречались обязательно, а не 1 из них.

Comment: То есть есть каждое из них(qwe+asd+zxc), но в любом порядке.

Comment: @Egor_K дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярки здесь даром не нужны.
Проверить, содержит ли поле подстроку, можно оператором LIKE.
Условий во WHERE может быть сколько угодно.
Если надо, чтобы они выполнялись все, то перечислять их надо через AND

Comment: Но у меня процедура, которая связывает данные из файла с мастер данными. Проверка идет по нескольким полям(в задаче одно из них) в различных комбинациях. Поэтому через where не получится.

Comment: Но все равно спасибо за ответ!